# inject services inside filters in nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, import, nestjs

I'm trying to inject `nestjs-config` inside the following exception handler i've created:

```
import { ExceptionFilter, Catch, ArgumentsHost, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectConfig } from 'nestjs-config';

@Injectable()
@Catch()
export class HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  constructor(
    @InjectConfig()
    private readonly config,
  ) {
    this.config = config.get('errors');
  }
  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    // some code here that calls this.config
  }
}
```

but it's returning undefined: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

this is how the exception handler is defined globally:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
app.useGlobalFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter());
await app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Can you add your AppModule code please? To me it looks like ConfigService is not available in the current context.

Comment: One note - you don't need `@Injectable()` since `@Catch()` is here already

Answer (score 4):

Ok so I've just realised that in your code you're creating the filter outside of the container therefore the ConfigService is not injected. There's a few ways to resolve this. One

```
ConfigService.load(path.resolve(__dirname, 'config', '*.ts'))

const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
app.useGlobalFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter(ConfigService));
await app.listen(3000);
```

Or

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {cors: true});
const config = app.get<ConfigService>(ConfigService);
app.useGlobalFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter(config));
await app.listen(3000);
```

Depending that your AppModule looks like this

```
@Module({
    imports: [ConfigModule.load(path.resolve(__dirname, 'config', '*.ts')],
})
export AppModule {}
```

Or like this:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {cors: true});
const httpExceptionFilter = app.get(HttpExpectionFilter);
app.useGlobalFilters(httpExpectionFilter);
```

Comment: tried both your ways but neither of them worked for the HttpExceptionFilter, everywhere else it works normally...

Answer (score 1):

solved it by calling the ConfigService as follows:

```
export class HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {

  constructor(private readonly config: ConfigService) {
    this.config = ConfigService.get('errors');
  }
  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    // some code here that calls this.config
  }
}
```

Comment: And how did you managed to inject the configservice inside a controller ?
` @Catch(new RpcExceptionFilter(ConfigService)) `
Doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

You can make the exception filter [request scoped](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes)

```js
import { ExceptionFilter, Catch, ArgumentsHost, Injectable, Scope } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectConfig } from 'nestjs-config';

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
@Catch()
export class HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  constructor(
    @InjectConfig()
    private readonly config,
  ) {
    this.config = config.get('errors');
  }
  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    // some code here that calls this.config
  }
}
```

Now with each request new instance of the `HttpExceptionFilter` gets created with its dependencies

Comment: I broke my brain a bit to run my unit-tests after added my service to scope Request.

Answer (score 0):

For the Nestjs V8, you could put this in the AppModule providers:

```
{
  provide: APP_FILTER,
  useClass: HttpExceptionFilter,
},
```